# How can I make Arduino IDE use Atmel's provided toolchain? (Linux/Ubuntu)

Tags: arduino-ide, compile, ubuntu, avr-toolchain, command-line

I have an Arduino based board using ATmega168PB, but so far only Atmel's provided toolchain supports this microcontroller. I can download the toolchain from Atmel's website, but I am not sure how to make the Arduino environment use it.

Answer (score 3):

In the directory for the new core create a new `platform.txt` and give the entry for `compiler.path` the location of the `bin/` directory containing the Atmel toolchain.

```
compiler.path=/path/to/bin/
```